# Function composition argument error

Tags: f#

I have the following code snippet:

```
let add n x = x + n
let times n x = x * n
let addTimes = add 5 >> times 5
addTimes 4
```

and this works without any problem. But when I change like this

```
let add n x = x + n
let times n x = x * n
let addTimes = add >> times
addTimes 4
```

I've got the compiling error

```
error FS0071: Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type '(int -> int)' for a type inference variable. Expecting a type supporting the operator '*' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function. Consider adding further type constraints
```

Why?

Comment: Function composition is basically f(g(x)), but your g(x) here returns a single value while f takes 2 arguments - how would composition be expected to work?

Comment: My problem is, I do not know how composition works. It so wired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `(>>)` is `('T1 -> 'T2) -> ('T2 -> 'T3) -> 'T1 -> 'T3`. I.e., it composes two *unary* functions – you are attempting to supply two binary functions, which is valid in general (though arguably not useful, or at the least unclear), but not for *your* function types:

Given that `(f >> g) x` is equivalent to `g(f(x))`, what would the expected outcome be when `f` is binary? In your case, `x` (`int`) is partially-applied to `add` (`int -> int -> int`), and that partial application (`(int -> int)`) is passed to `times` (also `int -> int -> int`), which obviously expects an `int` as its first parameter rather than the function type `(int -> int)`.